# Extracting double value from a string c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the double from my string.

```
buff = "VA VV_CELL1 3.55"
```

When i use the following code

```
private void GetLine(string msg, string buff, double numb)
{
    comPort.WriteLine(msg); 
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    buff = comPort.ReadExisting();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(buff, @".*?([-]{0,1} *\d+.\d+)");
    List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
        value = value.Replace(" ", "");
        doubles.Add(double.Parse(value));
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        numb = doubles[0];                
    } 
}
```

This code work for my other strings but "CELL1" contains a number so i dont get the wanted value "3.55" any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the goal of `Thread.Sleep` in your `foreach` loop

Comment: just test the value for any nonnumerical chars(excluding the decimal seperator) before parsing

Comment: You always want to extract the last number from a string?

Comment: I assume you want to capture both doubles and integers, otherwise you could write `\d+\.\d+`. You can capture a decimal preceded by whitespace with `\s+\d+(\.\d+)?`. If you want to capture only the last field, `\s+\d+(\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you don't simply split this string and take the last part?

```
string numberPart = buff.Split().Last();
double num;
bool validNum = double.TryParse(numberPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num);
```

Another way is to use `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`(which fails if there is no space):

```
string numberPart = buff.Substring(buff.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim();
```

---

To help on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886911/extracting-double-value-from-a-string-c-sharp#comment82740807_47886966):

I'd use a method that returns a `double?`(double that can be null):

```
double? GetNumber(string buff)
{
    string numberPart = buff.Split().Last();
    double num;
    bool validNum = double.TryParse(numberPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num);
    if (validNum)
        return num;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Now you can use the method and you even know whether the number could be parsed successfully or not:

```
double? result = GetNumber("VA VV_CELL1");
bool wasValid = result.HasValue;
if(wasValid)
{
   double value = result.Value;
}
```

Comment: Splitting generates a lot of temporary strings that can be very expensive in when parsing a large number of records. If the record is fixed length though, the lines short or the number of records small, regular expressions can be overkill

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: In OP's sample it generates 3 temp strings. I dont think this is too much overhead. However, you can also use `buff.Substring(buff.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim()`. Normally regex is much more expensive

Comment: Thx mate it helped a lot!

Comment: @TimSchmelter
` private void GetGet(string msg, string buff, double var)
        {
            comPort.WriteLine(msg);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            buff = comPort.ReadLine();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            string numberPart = buff.Split().Last();
            double num;
            bool validNum = double.TryParse(numberPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num);
            var = num;
        }
`
when i call my method GetGet("VA VV_CELL1", buff1, var1);
var1 is 0, why?

Comment: @xBehemoth: you either have to return `num` or make the parameter `var` `ref`. I'd prefer a method `double GetValue(string msg, string buff, double var){ ... return num;}`

Comment: @xBehemoth: i have edited my answer. But you noticed that this string is not valid? Or you want to return 1 in that case?

Comment: @TimSchmelter
the thing is i have many values and i need to save the values in different variables i have like 10 of them so i want to make a method to be called like this GetGet("VA VV_CELL1", buff1, var1); so i can save different values in different variables.

Comment: @xBehemoth: sure, just store the result in a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try, this regex expression : `\s+\d+(.)?\d+`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to capture both doubles and integers, otherwise you could write `\d+\.\d+`. This :

```
Regex.Matches("VA VV_CELL1 3.55",@"\d+\.\d+")[0]
```

Returns 3.55 but can't capture 355.

You can capture an integer or decimal preceded by whitespace with `\s+\d+(\.\d+)?`.

```
Regex.Matches("VA VV_CELL1 3.55",@"\s+\d+(\.\d+)?")[0]
```

Returns 3.55 while

```
Regex.Matches("VA VV_CELL1 355",@"\s+\d+(\.\d+)?")[0]
```

Returns 355

If you want to capture only the last field you can use `\s+\d+(\.\d+)?$`,eg:

```
Regex.Matches("VA VV_CELL1 3.54 3.55",@"\s+\d+(\.\d+)?$")[0]
```

Returns 3.55

You don't need to trim whitespace because `double.Parse` ignores it. You can change the pattern to capture the number in a separate group though, by surrounding the digits with parentheses :

```
Regex.Matches("VA VV_CELL1 3.54 3.55",@"\s+(\d+(\.\d+)?)$")[0].Groups[1]
```

You need to use `Groups[1]` because the first group always returns the entire capture